# Is there a reason why `strings.EqualFold` does not do a length comparison first?

Tags: string, go, unicode

A common practice to compare strings with case insensitivity is to explicitly check the length first:

```golang
if len(a) == len(b) && strings.EqualFold(a, b) { ... }
```

This seems to be a workaround as the [current implementation](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.4:src/strings/strings.go;l=1137) only does the length check when exhausted either of the two input strings.

Is there a reason why length check is not done first, performance-wise or otherwise?

Comment: Formally strings can be EqualFold while havong different length in bytes. So yes, there is a reason. The "common practice to compare strings with case insensitivity" might be common, but it is plain wrong (as it makes unwarranted assumptions of how Unicode works).

Comment: Note that the length check of the (correct) Go version does _not_ compare the length of the _input_ strings in the general case. See the test cases for examples, e.g. https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.4:src/strings/strings_test.go;l=1560

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The short answer is because 2 strings may have different length in Go, while still being equal under simple Unicode case-folding (so doing a length comparison first would not tell anything sure about case-folding equality).

The longer answer is: Go stores strings in memory as the [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) bytes, and the builtin [`len()`](https://pkg.go.dev/builtin#len) function reports the number of bytes in UTF-8 encoding. UTF-8 is a variable-length character encoding: it may use different number of bytes for a single unicode codepoint, so a matching case-folding codepoint may use different number of bytes in UTF-8.

See an example to prove this:

```
s1, s2 := "\u017F", "\u0073"
fmt.Println(s1, s2)

fmt.Println(len(s1), len(s2), strings.EqualFold(s1, s2))
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/RwUotlWffUZ)):

```
ſ s
2 1 true
```